# (SOLVED) Transaction not showing after resend (Bitcoin Core/Exodus)

Tags: transactions

**UPDATE: After several hours, the second transaction is now showing up on BlockCypher.**

I sent some bitcoin from my Bitcoin Core wallet to my Exodus wallet. The first time, I tried lowballing the fees and the transaction was eventually dropped (not showing up in blockcypher or other sites).

Using `-zapwallettxes` I was able to successfully recover the bitcoin.

After sending the bitcoin a second time (using the recommended fee), the second transaction is not showing up in blockcypher at all. The status shown in Bitcoin Core is "0/unconfirmed, in memory pool". Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: My transaction ID is `115c77086608cab30b92bab4316920787be8a886a5018f5d2eb5512a49a7b6f6`; again, it doesn't work on the several blockchain explorer sites I've used.

EDIT 2: After running `-zapwallettxes` again, the transaction disappears and the bitcoin shows up in my wallet. However, after I remove the command, the transaction re-appears.

Comment: It sounds like your second tx is simply unconfirmed. Have you checked any other block explorer websites? If you can post a tx ID or receiving address here someone may be able to help further.

Comment: My transaction id is `115c77086608cab30b92bab4316920787be8a886a5018f5d2eb5512a49a7b6f6` as shown in BTC. I've used several other blockchain explorers (blockchain.info, blockexplorer, btc.com) and none of them show my transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your wallet is not fully synced to the network, since multiple block explorers do not have a record of it. Ensure your wallet is synced, and then try rebroadcasting the tx

Comment: Bitcoin Core is fully up to date. I have re-synced the Exodus wallet; the first transaction (the one that was dropped) disappeared but the second one hasn't showed up. It seems like the Bitcoin Core wallet never sent the bitcoin in the first place. After running `-zapwallettxes` again the second transaction disappeared and the Bitcoin is back in my wallet. However, after removing `-zapwallettxes` the transaction reappears.

Comment: If the transaction isn't showing up in other block explorers, then I'm guessing your bitcoin core wallet isn't synced and communicating with the network. To be clear, this is different than just 'being up to date' (in terms of software version).